# Do Max-SMT benefit from incremental solving?

Tags: z3

Do Max-SMT benefit from incremental solving?
If yes, does Z3 support it? and how I can use it? Thanks.

Comment: As this is a general algorithmic question about, you may get a better answer on Programmers.SE. You could ask a moderator to port it.

Comment: @msanford algorithm questions are on-topic at both sites, and this question is a bit unclear. It should be improved before considering migration.

Comment: @Snowman Good point (especially given your pedigree). I often have trouble figuring out where a question of this type belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stackoverflow allows incremental questions, but Z3's optimization routines are non-incremental :-) 
The API exposes push/pop functions, but they are only for convenience. When it comes to solving, Z3 performs pre-processing on the entire set of asserted formulas and then invokes maximization routines. Even if there were no pre-processing, it is possibly an interesting question what it would mean to make core-(and correction set) based max-sat solvers incremental in a useful way.